# Custom JavaScript function queue

Tags: javascript, queue

For fun, I made a function queue in JavaScript.  I named it [tinyq](https://github.com/NTICompass/tinyq).  You can add functions to it, and each function is passed the next function in the queue.  You can also pass parameters to the functions, and they can return values.

```
function q(){
    var Q = [], t = this;
    this.length = 0;
    this.add = function (f){
        Q.push(f);
        this.length++;
    };
    this.run = function(){
        var n = Q.shift();
        this.length = Q.length;
        if(typeof n === 'function'){
            var a = Array.prototype.slice;
            return n.apply(window,[function(){
                return t.run.apply(t, a.call(arguments));
            }].concat(a.call(arguments)));
        }
    };
}
```

Here's a simple example of its use.

```
var Q = new q;
Q.add(function(next, A, B){
    return A + ": "+ next(B);
});
Q.add(function(next, C){
    return C + "123";
});
console.log(Q.length); // 2
console.log(Q.run("Test", "ABC")); // "Test: ABC123"
```

So, what do you think of my function queue?  Any improvements, or anything I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I was also trying to make this small, any suggestions on making it smaller?

Comment: I feel like I'm not really understanding the purpose behind this. It seems like really complicated function composition. I realize the sample is purposely simple, so how else could this be used in a way more complicated than functional composition?

Comment: @jdmichal: To be honest, I just wrote this for fun, with no reason for its existence.  Is there a better way to do function composition that would still work with a queue?

Comment: No worries; just trying to wrap my brain around the intended functionality. :) I'll add an answer to show how I would do simple function composition.

Comment: Hi @RocketHazmat I just came up with my own `Queue` implementation a few days ago when answering an SO question. Here is my CR OP: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/28380/3163 ^_^ Have fun with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure where queue semantics are coming into play here. If you just walked up to me and told me you had a function queue for JavaScript, I would expect that I could add a bunch of functions to it, and then it would call them in sequence. But that's not what I'm seeing here.

What I am seeing is a really weirdly formed function composition. Here's how I would do the sample given:

```
// Create function to show a value with a label.
// Note that it takes a value function, rather than a pure value.
// It also takes any number of arguments for that function, as an array.
var showWithLabel = function (label, valueFunction, valueArguments) {
    return (label + ": " + valueFunction.apply(undefined, valueArguments));
};

// Create a function to append "123" onto a string.
var append123 = function (string) {
    return (string + "123");
};

// Simple call to execute them together.
showWithLabel("Test", append123, ["ABC"]);

// Actually composite them into a new function.
// This function is the equivalent of the run function.
var composite = function (label, value) {
    return showWithLabel(label, append123, [value]);
};

// Now call the composite.
composite("Test", "ABC");
```

Please comment and discuss here. I want to have a conversation about this, because I feel like there's probably some functionality I'm not understanding about the queue.

Comment: This queue can support adding functions and calling them in sequence.  Just remove all parameters (except `next`) and it'll work that way.  I added the parameter thing for fun.  Guess it really doesn't have much real use.  This is a neat example, btw.  Nice and simple.

Comment: Oh, I see. You can call `run` multiple times and it will keep reducing the queue down. I must admit that I also don't see much use for that, and I have done a pretty good amount of browser JavaScript coding. Interesting idea though.

Comment: You can call `run` to run the next item and reduce the queue.  Each item is passed `next`.  Calling `next` will also call the next function and reduce the queue.  Both `run` and `next` can pass parameters to the function in the queue that's being ran.

Answer (score 8):

I'm still trying to wrap my head around what exactly is happening in that `apply`/`call` mass :-)

But that may be a hint, that those three lines aren't really well readable. I'm aware you want to keep it small, but unless the code needs to be really, really fast (which I doubt it does) I would prefer readability over shortness.

In that line, I would prefer to have long, more expressive variable names. It be better to use complete words instead of `Q`, `t`, `n`, `a` etc.

If in the end, shortness is still important, then use a JavaScript compressor.

BTW, you should keep JavaScript naming conventions in mind, too. Constructor functions ("classes") should be named with capital letters (`Q` instead of `q`) and fields should use small letters (`q` instead of `Q`).

Just out of interest: Can you give a concrete use case for this kind of queue?

Comment: I really don't have a real use case right now, this is just something I made for fun.  I was trying to make a queue like jQuery's `.queue` with more features.  Yeah, the `.apply`/`.call` thing is the heart of this script, and I agree it looks odd.  I can try to explain it.  `a.call(arguments)` turns the arguments "array" into a real array, so I can pass it to `apply`.  `n.apply` calls the next function in the queue, and `t.run.apply` is a reference to `run` which when called triggers the next function in the queue.