# Javascript Queue Object

Tags: javascript, queue

I created a `Queue` object when [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17528961/561731) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17528749/561731) and I was wondering if it could do with some improvement.

Here is the current code:

```
var Queue = (function () {

    Queue.prototype.autorun = true;
    Queue.prototype.running = false;
    Queue.prototype.queue = [];

    function Queue(autorun) {
        if (typeof autorun !== "undefined") {
            this.autorun = autorun;
        }
        this.queue = []; //initialize the queue
    };

    Queue.prototype.add = function (callback) {
        var _this = this;
        //add callback to the queue
        this.queue.push(function () {
            var finished = callback();
            if (typeof finished === "undefined" || finished) {
                //  if callback returns `false`, then you have to 
                //  call `next` somewhere in the callback
                _this.dequeue();
            }
        });

        if (this.autorun && !this.running) {
            // if nothing is running, then start the engines!
            this.dequeue();
        }

        return this; // for chaining fun!
    };

    Queue.prototype.dequeue = function () {
        this.running = false;
        //get the first element off the queue
        var shift = this.queue.shift();
        if (shift) {
            this.running = true;
            shift();
        }
        return shift;
    };

    Queue.prototype.next = Queue.prototype.dequeue;

    return Queue;

})();
```

Is there anything that I can expand on or improve in this Object? 
Should anything be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the code is quite simple. That's a good thing already.

Some things can be improved though:

- Always create the `autorun` property. It will help your compiler. See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28344/should-i-put-default-values-of-attributes-on-the-prototype-to-save-space) for more details. Besides, it's simpler to read. Just go with this:

  ```
  function Queue(autorun) {
      this.autorun = autorun;
  }
  ```

On another note, adding the properties on the prototype is just as bad, read the link I already showed to understand why.

- Maybe it's only me, but the first lines are disturbing because they're before the "class" declaration. So it looks like they belong to the external object, while they actually belong to the hoisted function.
- You don't need `typeof variable === "undefined"`. `variable === undefined` is enough because you know for sure the identifier exists.
- `var shift = this.queue.shift();` w-w-w-what's this variable name?! You probably mean `var first ...`. Use descriptive variable names.
- I'm not sure you want to return `shift` in `dequeue`. Don't you mean `this`? Chaining is fun!

Comment: 1 -- Well I want the option for a user **not** to pass in the `autorun` option (so by default it will be true). 

2 -- And the variables on the prototype are hoisted to the function call within the scope -- At least I believe that they are.

3 -- Yes, My variable naming is terrible

4 -- CHAINING IS **FUN** 

2.5 --- I find the speed of `typeof` vs the other route is minimal.

Comment: @Neal 1. It's ok, the property will just be `undefined`. But at least the generated class (by the compiler) will be the same no matter how you instantiate the object. 2. They are. But it's just wrong on a readability level. Principle of least surprise.

Comment: If the property is undefined then my check if `autorun` is true will fail in the `add` function so the queue will never autorun unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: @Neal if you don't pass anything, it will be `undefined`. If you pass `true`, it will be `true`. So your `add` function will work just as well. Or is there something else I'm not getting?

Comment: Yes but `if(undefined){/*will never get here*/}` --> Which I do not want. I want, be default for the queue to **automatically** run.

Comment: @Neal that's not what your code currently does though. Right now, it will be `undefined` by default, and something else if you pass it something else.

Comment: Right now if you pass **nothing** then autorun will be `true`. Which is what I wanted, and what is does.

Comment: OH I SEE ITS BECAUSE OF THE PROTOTYPE. Oh god, change this. See how much you had to say to convince me how the code actually works? You just had the best proof that your code is definitely not readable.

Comment: You could change `autorun` to `manualrun`, reversing the sense. Then you could just do `this.manualrun = !!manualrun` in the constructor and dispense with the property on the prototype. And you'd have to change the check for `this.autorun` in `.add`.

Comment: Or you could just handle this logic in the constructor and set `autorun` to the right value.

Comment: Sure. I guess it depends on whether you want a default parameter.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine nothing to do with prototype... I want people to be able to do `new Queue;` without explicitly having to say `new Queue(true);`

Comment: I am changing the `queue` variable in the class out of the prototype.